# Remove constraints iOS

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I try to remove constraints. I want to different constraints on portrait and landscape. If I change the orientation to Portrait I call the function **setupConstrainsInPortrait** and conversely. I have two functions.

This function setup Portrait mode.

```
func setupConstrainsInPortrait() {

    view.addSubview(myView)

    myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(switchKmM)

    switchKmM.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    switchKmM.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    switchKmM.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    switchKmM.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(speedLbl)

    speedLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    speedLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
    speedLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    speedLbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

This function setup landscape mode.

```
    func setupConstrainsInLandScape() {
    view.addSubview(myView)

    myView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(switchKmM)

    switchKmM.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.rightAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    switchKmM.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    switchKmM.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    switchKmM.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

I use these functions in viewWillTransition

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("landscape!")
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        setupConstrainsInLandScape()
        self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()


    }
    else {
        print("portrét")
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupConstrainsInPortrait()
        self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    }
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

The problem is, that constraints(from portrait function) in landscape mode aren't deleted

I hope that someone can help me... Thank you

Comment: What's the question / problem? Give desired outcome vs. actual outcome.

Comment: The problem is, that constraints(from portrait function) in landscape mode aren't deleted

Comment: "constraints(from portrait function) in landscape mode aren't deleted" No surprise there. I don't see any code that would delete them. All you do is say `isActive = true`. Never once do you say `isActive = false`. So you just keep adding and adding constraints without ever removing any. What do you expect, in that case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not doing enough work. You need to retain references to all the constraints you activate, so that you can deactivate them later. For example, you are saying:

```
myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width).isActive = true
```

Instead, you need to say something like

```
self.myConstraints1 = [
    myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50),
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width),
]
```

Now activate all those constraints. Proceed the same way throughout.

Thus, when the time comes to deactivate constraints because the orientation is changing, you have references to them and can do so.

Comment: Nothing to do with "swift". If you're serious about a problem, you're willing at least to look at the basic documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint

Comment: I have a weak reference to the view I am adding. I did exactly as u said. when I deactivate the stored constraints and then remove the view from the superview. my weak reference is still holding the view. even that the view have no superview anymore!

Comment: And I clear the array after removing the view from its superview.

Comment: the superview is a uitabbar. can't remove the constraints from it because its controlled by a uitabbarcontroller.

Comment: is it safe to just set the weak reference to nil. I am adding(creating new)/removing this view continuously in my screen

Comment: @hasan The Ask Question button is at the top right of the page.

Answer (score -8):

You can remove your constraints using:

```
myView.constraints.removeAll()
```

Before setting the new ones.

Comment: Look the question before down vote. He is asking how to remove the constraints. I answered how.

Comment: I did. He didn't even stated his result or his attempted result. He asked how to remove and I did answer.

Comment: The constraints property on a view is immutable - you can't use the mutable function `removeAll()`. I think what you meant to say was `myView.removeConstraints(myView.constraints)`