# How to remove constraint that is added programmatically

Tags: swift, constraints

How to remove this constraint programmatically. please help

```
cell.textView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.textView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                                                           toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 54))
```

that code is added in tablecells .i want to remove when keyboard hide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove constraints iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944479/remove-constraints-ios)

Comment: As per Apple Documentations -- [Remove a constraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622659-removeconstraint)

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you want to remove just this one constraint, without interfering with default ones. The simplest way would be, of course, to just keep a reference to this constraint and to disable it.

```
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.textView, 
                               attribute: .height, 
                               relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, 
                                  toItem: nil, 
                               attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                              multiplier: 1.0, constant: 54)
cell.textView.addConstraint(constraint)
strongReferenceToConstraint = constraint

/// somewhere else 

cell.textView.removeConstraint(strongReferenceToConstraint)
```

But if you can't keep reference to it, or for some reason it's not accessible to you, you can try iterating over all constraints of this view and finding the one on `height` by checking its `firstAttribute` property

```
for constraint in cell.textView.constraints
{
    if constraint.firstAttribute == .height
    {
        constraint.isActive = false
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: This exemple will let a reference to this constraint is not better to use removeConstraint(_: constraint) instead of  yourClassVariable.isActive = false ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.textView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                                                           toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 54)

constraint.isActive = false
```